# How many connections to mongo can i mention in airflow?

Tags: mongodb, airflow, database-connection

I have two mongo connections in my airflow mongo_default & mongo_test.

I want to use mongo test but it somehow goes to mongo_default and i cannot figure out why:

```
hook = MongoHook(mongo_conn_id='mongo_test')
```

error i am getting : Error connecting to MongoDB : [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Can someone help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

#### For `apache-airflow-providers-mongo` versions greater or equal 3.6.0

- `mongo_conn_id` is valid argument
- `conn_id` is deprecated argument, and will be removed in the future

#### For `apache-airflow-providers-mongo` versions prior 3.6.0

According to the `airflow.providers.mongo.hooks.mongo.MongoHook` [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-mongo/3.5.0/_api/airflow/providers/mongo/hooks/mongo/index.html#airflow.providers.mongo.hooks.mongo.MongoHook) you should use `conn_id` argument, and `mongo_conn_id` has no affect.

```py
hook = MongoHook(conn_id='mongo_test')
```

Comment: i followed this documentation https://www.mongodb.com/developer/products/mongodb/mongodb-apache-airflow/

Comment: Well that is an error into this article. AFAIK MongoHook use `conn_id` for ages and there was attempt to switch to [`mongo_conn_id`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/28946) however unfortunetly it wasn't completed

Comment: BTW I've just raise a [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/36896) which might be included into the next (or next after the next) version of `apache-airflow-providers-mongo`